# Scrapy Table column and rows doesn't work

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrapy the table of this page, but the scrapped data is only in one column, and in some case the data doesn't appear. Also I use the shell to see if the Xpath is correct (I use the Xpath helper to identify these xpath)

```
import scrapy
class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrape-xpath'
    start_urls = [
        'http://explorer.eu/contents/food/28?utf8=/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for flv in response.xpath('//html/body/main/div[4]'):

            yield {
                'Titulo': flv.xpath('//*@id="chromatography"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/th/strong/a/text()"]/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/a[2]').extract(),
            'contenido': flv.xpath('//*@id="chromatography"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/a[2]/text()').extract(),
             'clase': flv.xpath('//*[@id="chromatography"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/text()').extract(),
            'Subclase': flv.xpath('//*[@id="chromatography"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a/text').extract(),
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example URL given, it's not exactly obvious what the values should be and how extraction should generalize for page containing more records. So I tried a different page with multiple records, let's see if the result gets you what you need. Here's ready to run code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class PhenolExplorerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'phenol-explorer'
    start_urls = ['http://phenol-explorer.eu/contents/food/29?utf8=/']

    def parse(self, response):
        chromatography = response.xpath('//div[@id="chromatography"]')
        title = chromatography.xpath('.//tr/th[@class="outer"]/strong/a/text()').extract_first()
        for row in chromatography.xpath('.//tr[not(@class="header")]'):
            class_ = row.xpath('./td[@rowspan]/text()').extract_first()
            if not class_:
                class_ = row.xpath('./preceding-sibling::tr[td[@rowspan]][1]/td[@rowspan]/text()').extract_first()
            subclass = row.xpath('./td[not(@rowspan)][1]/a/text()').extract_first()
            #content = row.xpath('./td[not(@rowspan)][2]/a[2]/text()').extract_first()
            content = row.xpath('./td[not(@rowspan)][2]/text()').extract_first()
            yield {
                'title': title.strip(),
                'class': class_.strip(),
                'subclass': subclass.strip(),
                'content': content.strip(),
            }
```

Basically, it iterates over individual rows of the table and extracts the data from corresponding fields, yielding an item once complete information is collected.

Comment: the results are not the expected. Thank you for the help. Now I have a better code, but need some improvements.

Comment: And what the results shall be? Maybe we can sort it out.

Comment: I need the same results, but in aglycones, in "display options" -> show values expressed as: aglycones equivalents

Comment: Then you need to change the starting URL to [http://phenol-explorer.eu/contents/food/29?utf8=/&options%5Bshow_aglycones%5D=on](http://phenol-explorer.eu/contents/food/29?utf8=/&options%5Bshow_aglycones%5D=on). The table now looks a bot different so you might have to change the extraction code a bit as well.

Comment: Official [Scrapy tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) is a great starting point. Also [Scrapinghub blog](https://blog.scrapinghub.com) contains a lot of practical tips.

Comment: http://phenol-explorer.eu/contents/food/29?utf8=/&options%5B‌​show_aglycones%5D=on, doesn't work, the .csv is empty, the problem is the Xpath??

Comment: Yes, when using view as aglycones equivalents, content is not surrounded by `a` element, so XPath for content extraction has to change. I updated my answer and the code, original extraction for content is commented out and replaced with the one working for your new starting URL.

Comment: This woooorks!!!thank you Sir!!Anything I can do to help you, do not hesitate to contact me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for row in response.css('#chromatography table tr:not(.header)'):
    yield {'titulo': row.xpath('./preceding-sibling::tr/th[contains(@class, "outer")]//a/text()').extract_first().strip(),
           'clase': row.xpath('./preceding-sibling::tr/th[contains(@class, "inner")]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
           'subclase': row.xpath('./td[2]//text()').extract_first().strip(),
           'contenido': row.css('.content_value a::text').extract_first().strip()}
```

remember that the inner loop selectors should also be relative to node `flv` in your case, selecting with `//` is a global selector so it'll grab everything.
It's also better to inspect the real html code, because the browser might render some other code different to the actual html received (for example the `tbody` tags)

Comment: were you able to try this approach?

Comment: yes, but don't run, there is a problem with the ":" in the first line!!I use the shell to check the Xpath and CSS, how I can see the real html (I use fn+ F12).Thank you Sir!!

Comment: it should run if you put the code into the `parse` method, what error does it show? about the html you can use curl, save scrapy's output into a file or use the developer tools from your browser (sometimes javascript messes up the html, so it depends on the site)